# how to compress my mp3 files to reduce apk file size?

Tags: android, compression, mp3, apk

I'm developing an android application that has over 111MB of mp3 files.

I need to compress these files and put them in my package (like raw folder) and after my app was installed on a device, it decompresses files to use them.
How could I do this? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce mp3 file size by reducing the bit rate. Reducing the bit rate will result in smaller file size but lower quality, so you have to check what works best for you. You can improve the quality by using Variable Bit Rate (VBR) instead of Constant Bit Rate (CBR).

You can do that using a software such as [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Use Super C freeware, convert to AAC will also help.